# Raspberry pi remote access active session

Tags: raspbian, ssh, screen, remote

When I remote access the raspberry pi with software now installed I do not get to access the current session displayed on my tv, but rather a new session.

Is there software to access the current running session so I can use the keyboard and mouse connected to my laptop to control my raspberry pi?

ATM I use putty and Xming to access my PI, but that creates a new user session instead of the active one.

Comment: Have you tried a VNC server? http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server

Comment: will try that when im home from work, tnx.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install x11vnc daemon on the linux distro with runs on Pi. Then run that command;

```
x11vnc -display :0 -usepw -noxdamage -ncache 10 -ncache_cr -listen IP_of_pi -allow allowed_ip_address
```

After ran the command, connect to pi with any VNC client.

Answer (score 3):

You need `x11vnc`. This will allow you to connect to the same session on the TV.

Comment: This answer could do with expanding.

Answer (score 1):

You should install VNC.

Basically you need to follow the instructions [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server).

The basics are:

1. Install tightvncserver: `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`.
2. Make a shell strict with the start command.
3. Add an init script.
4. Install the tightvnc viewer from the [website](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php).
5. Connect up.

> I might add more help later, if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

On my standard RPi I only need to run x11vnc without any parameters to be able to control the live session on the Pi with the TightVNC client on my Windows laptop. A couple of things did fool me for a while though, there must be a space between -display and the :0 bit, and if you've had an aborted session, you must either kill it on the Pi (eg vncserver kill :0) reboot it, or use a different display number.  You also need to check the port that x11vnc is using, as displayed in the text after you run it.  After a day of researching, it now works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a remote connection start after using a shortened version of the command that gurcanozturk shared.

After installing x11vnc, I edited

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

to run the following command:

```
x11vnc -display :0 -usepw -noxdamage -ncache 10 -ncache_cr
```

This allows using VNC to connect once then you would need to reboot the device in order to make another connection.

To connect with VNC use the

```
IP_of_pi:5900
```

This should get you connected up and working.