# Mirroring the RPi onto my laptop

Tags: ssh, remote

I have managed to have the RPi's GUI with the aid of [XRDP](http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-from.html) in my windows desktop.

My RPi is in the same network as my laptop but connected to a TV.

So I am using the RDC (Remote Desktop Connection) to do log on and browse the net, reboot and all the rest of it - and it works great - *but* - and the desktop I see is not mirrored on to the TV.

The only thing I can mirror is if I create a file on the desktop, and then delete. These are the only instances when I can make a change on the TV screen.

**Q:** Why isn't the RPi replicating what I do in RDC onto the TV screen? How can I make it replicate in real time on to the TV screen?

---

***Edit:*** *(11/09/2015)* 
I would like to mirror the image on the TV screen on to my laptop with an alternative option to VNC. VNC is terribly laggy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of :http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/tightvncserver-show-the-same-screen-on-hdmi-and-vncclient also have a look at this one as it targets xrdp : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7444/remote-desktop-with-xrdp

Comment: RDC is a big-iron (cough Windows) solution. Because Unices support multiple users & multiple heads (since the 1960s), your Pi obligingly creates a new "desktop session" for the RDC head.